# C: Segfault when writing string concatenating function

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a string concatenating in C. I'm not allowed to use strcat. My program compiles without errors. But when I run it, I get a segfault. Can someone tell me what's wrong? Thanks. Here's my code

```
char* concat(char** strs, unsigned int nstrs)
{
  unsigned int outlen = 0;
  char* output;
  int x;
  int y;

  for(x = 0; x < nstrs ; x++) {
    outlen += strlen(strs[x]);
   }

  output = (char *) malloc(outlen * sizeof(char));

  for(x = 0; x < nstrs ; x++) {
    for(y = 0 ; y < strlen(strs[x]) ; y++) {
     output[x+y] = strs[x][y];
}  
}

      return output;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int strsize = 0;
  int x;

  for(x = 0; x < argc; x++) {
    strsize += strlen(argv[x+1]);
  }

  char** strs;
  strs = (char* *) malloc(sizeof(char)*strsize);

  for(x = 0; x < argc; x++) {
    strs[x] = argv[x+1];
  }

  concat(strs, (argc - 1));

  printf("%s", concat(strs, (argc -1)));

  free(strs);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ``output[x+y]`` will create surprising output ;) Better have a ``writePosition`` variable you increment each time you write a char to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strs = (char* *) malloc(sizeof(char)*strsize);
```

should be

```
strs = malloc(sizeof(char *)* <num of pointers>);
```

`strsize` should include `\0` character in each string.

Even if you fix this there is array out of bound access

```
  for(x = 0; x < argc; x++) {
    strsize += strlen(argv[x+1]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is

```
strsize += strlen(argv[x+1]);
```

When `x` is 1 less than `argc`, then by saying `argv[x+1]`, you're accessing out of bound memory [Remember, array indexing starts from `0`].

Also, please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Then again, the memory allocation logic for `char** strs;` is faulty. IMO, what you need is something like

```
strs = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc-1));
```

Lastly, as other answers suggested, you need to allocate memory for `output` as one more byte than that of the source string length calculated using `strlen()` as `strlen()` does not count the terminating `null` required for a string representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
strs = (char* *) malloc(sizeof(char)*strsize);
```

Your stars don't add up. If you want to allocate an array of `char*`, why are you using `sizeof(char)`?

```
output = (char *) malloc(outlen * sizeof(char));
```

Here your `sizeof` is right, but you are forgetting about the NUL termination of strings. You need to allocate one extra character, and then set it to `'\0'`.